# Determining a group of duplicates and finding its max/highest no

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, grouping, formula

Unsure if the solution is VBA/Macro or a formula in excel. However the goal is copying Value of the Highest/Max Term # within a group of accounts having the same account name to it's corresponding AValue. [Image below]

Note: The accounts are already sorted and cannot be sorted to another format as it deals with 7000+ entries

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem through 2 ways:

1: You can sort your data based on column **A** and column **B** both ascending. then you can insert the following formula in cell **D3** and copy it down.

```
=IF(A3=A4;"";C3)
```

2: You can also use the following formula in cell **D3** and copy it down:

```
{=IF(MAX($B$3:$B$15*IF($A$3:$A$15=A3;1;0)) = B3;C3;"")}
```

Note that first you must enter

> =IF(MAX($B$3:$B$15*IF($A$3:$A$15=A3;1;0)) = B3;C3;"")

in cell D3 and after finishing the formula and while you are in edit mode, you must press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** together. Excel automatically generate the above formula. If you write **"{"** and **"}"** manually, the formula won't work.